# How Do I Compile Copied and Pasted Files in a Visual Studio Project Solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just created a new project in Visual Studio 2019 and copied a bunch of files into the source/repos/project directory but they don't compile. I am guessing that is because these files were not created using Visual Studio.

Is there an easy way to make sure that the Project compiles all files in the directory even if they were created elsewhere? Right now all the files that I pasted in are treated like hidden files and the build option is a greyed out "None" instead of "Compile."

The files in question are all folders, PHP files, CSS, Javascript, etc.

See screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeJSE.jpg)

Comment: None of the files you name are compiled in any form. Both PHP and Javascript are interpreted, and CSS is just visual rules for browsers, not compiled code. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: None of the files you've listed require a compiler. There's nothing for Visual Studio to compile at all.